# Why am I seeing this ~$ML infront of the a file named HTML Tid Bits.docx in Git Terminal?

Tags: git, github

I'm seeing two versions of the same word doc file.

modified:   HTML Tid Bits.docx 
 modified:   ~$ML Tid Bits.docx

I did a hard reset to unstage my files. Then, I modified the file and after that, I ran `git status` . I now have two modified versions :

modified:   HTML Tid Bits.docx 
  modified:   ~$ML Tid Bits.docx

of the same file showing in the terminal screen but not in the file explorer GUI.
 Questions : 
1. Why did this happen ?
2. How can i put this file into .gitignore since it doesn't exist in my file explorer GUI ?

[screenshot of my terminal screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8r0w.png)

Comment: That’s not a usual git thing. Do you have the file open somewhere?

Comment: Yep, looks like something Word might create. If it's not open now, did Word recently crash while it was open? Actually, the file's showing as _modified_, not new. This might be an "echo" of having the file open in Word earlier and / or on another machine. Maybe even by another developer.

Comment: (Aside: Git isn't ideally suited for binary formats like DOCX. I'm not sure what you're doing, but a text-based editing format like Makdown, ReST, LaTeX, Org Mode, etc. might be a better choice than Word if you're planning to version with Git.)

Comment: @Chris right, I thought that it might be Word’s version of a .swp file.

Comment: So if understood correctly, if the file was open in Word and i ran `git status` it'd show me the `~$ML`

Comment: File names either starting with, or ending with, a tilde are often used by various editors as temporary and/or backup files. There's no guarantee that this is what is happening here, but it's definitely a possibility.